# How to block an IP address on internet correctly?

Tags: security, web-applications

In some cases, you might want to block hacker from your system by using IP addresses.
However, sometime it is more difficult due to existent of ISP proxy.

From the view of system, we see many traffic/connection/burceforce/wrong password from same IP meanwhile it could be a HTTP proxy or IPv6 gateway or similar. But it might not smart enough to tell is that normal or abnormal.

What's the suggested way to block those bad access without degrade user experience(e.g. too many captcha) to whom are innocent?

Comment: To whom vote to close this question.

I am looking for a programming way solution, some kind of pattern or design that can build-in in generic webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you consider this "Degrading user experience" But you can code MAX_TRIES for the login to give the user only few tries -to login then if all tries are wrong he is blocked from logging for a while- to prevent Brute forcing the login.

And for other connection you can install mod_bw for apache then limit the connection limit per IP using this htaccess command

```
MaxConnection all 3
```

Comment: blocking of userid will not help as the attacker could have millions rows of userid-password dictionary for him to try.

Comment: Don't block the userid, block the user IP, like in vbulletin forum software, Max tries = 5 and every login is count and ignoring what the ID he is trying to login with, and if the 5 tries failed he is banned for 15 minutes.

Comment: Then back to the original question, there are so many HTTP proxy or IPv6 gateway which we don't want to block.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should limit the login rate for each UserId.
2. After X mistakes, you can block a UserId till the user will reply to a special e-mail. This way, the user will also know that someone is trying to log into his account.
3. You can map source IP address into a specific country, and allow a user to log-in only from a predefined list of countries (user selection).
4. You can temporarily block a group of IP addresses (for example 172.16.254.*) if there are many false attempts from the same group. Many hackers just change the last octet.